# VirtualBox Web Service missing after clean installation on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: virtualbox

I just set up a new dedicated server with a clean installation of Ubunutu 18.04.1 LTS minimal. I'm trying to install VirtualBox with PHPVirtualBox, preferably using VirtualBox 6, but also willing to settle for VirtualBox 5 if that's what it takes to work. ;-)

This is what I did after the installation of the OS:

```
apt update
apt upgrade
apt dist-upgrade
apt install virtualbox
```

The installation seems to have worked:

```
root@Ubuntu-1804-bionic-64-minimal ~ # vboxmanage --version
5.2.18_Ubuntur123745
```

But at this point, from my experience with previous versions of Ubuntu an VirtualBox, there should be four services installed (aka the respective files present in /etc/init.d): vboxautostart-service, vboxballoonctrl-service, vboxdrv and vboxweb-service

However, the /etc/init.s directory looks like this:

```
root@Ubuntu-1804-bionic-64-minimal /etc/init.d # ls -la
total 128
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr  3 22:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 82 root root 4096 Apr  3 23:02 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4335 Mar 22  2018 apparmor
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 1071 Aug 22  2015 atd
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 1232 Apr 19  2018 console-setup.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 2489 May  6  2012 cpufrequtils
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 3049 Nov 16  2017 cron
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 2813 Nov 15  2017 dbus
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  985 Mar  4  2018 grub-common
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 2363 Jul 17  2017 haveged
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 3809 Feb 14  2018 hwclock.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 1479 Feb 15  2018 keyboard-setup.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 2044 Aug 15  2017 kmod
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 6912 May  6  2012 loadcpufreq
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  695 Dec  3  2017 lvm2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  571 Dec  3  2017 lvm2-lvmetad
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  586 Dec  3  2017 lvm2-lvmpolld
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 2653 Mar  7  2018 mdadm
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 1249 Mar  7  2018 mdadm-waitidle
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 1191 Jan 17  2018 procps
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 4355 Dec 13  2017 rsync
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 2864 Jan 14  2018 rsyslog
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 3837 Jan 26  2018 ssh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 5974 Apr 20  2018 udev
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 1306 Mar 15  2018 uuidd
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 6444 Nov 11  2017 virtualbox
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 2757 Jan 20  2017 x11-common
```

When I check if the kernel modules are loaded, as described in [this seemingly fine tutorial](https://www.ostechnix.com/install-oracle-virtualbox-ubuntu-16-04-headless-server/), via `systemctl status vboxdrv`, the output is:

```
root@Ubuntu-1804-bionic-64-minimal ~ # systemctl status vboxdrv
Unit vboxdrv.service could not be found.
```

When I try ot enable the VirtualBox Web Service, as described in the [VirtualBox Web Service documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#vboxwebsrv-daemon), via `systemctl enable vboxweb-service`, the output is:

```
root@Ubuntu-1804-bionic-64-minimal ~ # systemctl enable vboxweb-service
Failed to enable unit: Unit file vboxweb-service.service does not exist.
```

The same happens when I manually add the virtualbox.org package source and analogously try to install VirtualBox 6. It looks like three services that should be present are missing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: Tested with ***VirtualBox 6.0*** and it's working.

---

These services are not installed by default on the Ubuntu version you are using. However, you can download the official scripts that provide these services.

To do so, simply copy and paste these commands into the terminal and hit the enter. This will download the scripts and add them via `update-rc.d` to the start up scripts.

```
cd /etc/init.d/
services=(vboxautostart-service vboxweb-service vboxballoonctrl-service)
base_url="https://www.virtualbox.org/svn/vbox/trunk/src/VBox/Installer/linux"
for service in "${services[@]}"
    do
      wget "${base_url}/${service}".sh -O "${service}" \
      && chmod +x "$service"  \
      && update-rc.d "$service" defaults 90 10
    done
```

- About the `vboxdrv`:

It's not a service, but a module and needs to be loaded. You can run `modprobe vboxdrv` to load the module, but usually it's automatically loaded during the `virtualbox` installation.

To check if it's really loaded you can run

```
# modprobe -n --first-time vboxdrv
```

Or you can use `modinfo` to verify if the `vboxdrv` kernel module is loaded:

```
# modinfo vboxdrv
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-47-generic/misc/vboxdrv.ko
version:        6.0.4 r128413 (0x00290008)
...
```

After you are done with all these things, simply reboot.

After the restart, you can run `service --status-all | grep vbox` to verify that the services are running.

You should see an output similar to this:

```
 [ ? ]  vboxautostart-service
 [ + ]  vboxballoonctrl-service
 [ + ]  vboxweb-service
```

Now, you can also control these services via `systemctl`, i.e. `systemctl status vboxautostart-service`.

---

For more information about the configuration options of each Oracle VM VirtualBox service, see the official manual:

- Web Service: [page 243 (254/361)](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/UserManual.pdf)
- Autostart Service: [page 248 (259/361)](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/UserManual.pdf)

Comment: THIS IS A LIFESAVER. In lubuntu 18.04 this is also the same problem , this causes a login [server ]error in genymotion. , doing this in a sudo console and rebooting fixed it! 7u7